# Drop Down List Selected Index changed not working in Update panel

Tags: c#, webforms, updatepanel

I have a drop down list in UpdatePanel_2, it gets populated when Button_1 is clicked in UpdatePanel_1.

My ddlist markup is,

```
<asp:DropDownList id="drop1" runat="server"  EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

then code behind is,

```
 protected void Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { }
```

**I also tried putting AutoPostback=true to my DropDownList, still no success.**

I also added triggre to update panel 2 but no gain,

```
       <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="drop1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

**I am populating DropDownList using a button not PAGE LOAD METHOD PLEASE READ before answering.
Thanks**

Comment: We cannot tell, what is not working if your SelectedIndex method is empty. Please provide more code.

Comment: @Serv did you ever heard of break points while debugging ?

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression the code inside was bugged, not the the selected index changed does not get fired at all. Sorry - my bad.

Comment: you have to keep `AutoPostBack=true` in all the cases

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the data to populate the `DropDownList` in the `Page_Load` event and always check `IspostBack`:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 //DropDownList configuration
}
```

Use `EnableViewState`:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddDepPlans" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" />
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: If you read first line of my post, it saying that I am not populating ddl using page_load method, thanks

Comment: How was this the answer to your question?
I have exactly the same issue with the difference that I don't have my DDL in my front-markup but create it entirely in code-behind. My SelectedIndexChanged event won't fire, no matter what I do.

Comment: `EnableViewState` was the key in my case

Comment: I wish I had the reputation to upvote this. It's a rookie mistake that I made that ended up giving me the same problem as the original poster. ALWAYS CHECK THE POSTBACK STATE. I could NOT figure out why I didn't have access to the SelectedValue. Turns out that since I wasn't checking the postback onload, my DropDownList was having its datasource reset on every click, thus also resetting the SelectedValue!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. My problem was that the values of my ListItems were all the same :D

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilterLogins" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="All"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Some"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Some more"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

It should be like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilterLogins" runat="server" Visible="true" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="All"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Some"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Some more"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Hope this helps. This might be hard to find sometimes :)

Comment: Spend 2 hours then I found your answer. It helped

Answer (score 1):

Please, when you initialize it in Page_Load() check if not is postback. If you don't do it, you will always set the default value, and this replaces the value setted in the event.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
//DropDownList configuration
}
```

Comment: sorry :S ? I am not sure what you are trying to say sir

Comment: I'm saying that you need populate the dropdownlist inside the !IsPostBack condition, if not, everytime you did a postback you lost the selectedvalue property

Comment: I want to do partial post back sir

Comment: @user13814 partial postback is a kind of postback. Yo need to do what I said before, too.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you said sir now but no help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442809/drop-down-list-resets

Answer (score 0):

You can use Init event instead of SelectIndexChanged.
It worked fine for me.
Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

It was also a wired problem for me. finally It was because of identical listitems in the dropdown as shown below. during development you may use same items just for testing. change them.

```
<asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
```