# Drop Down List resets

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webforms, controls, updatepanel

My drop down list resets to default when I try to select a item, and it also doesn't trigger's code behind method when I put a line break and try to debug it:

Here's markup,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bringPOPup() 
    {     
        $.blockUI({message: $('#anotherUP'), css: { width: '600px' } });
    }
</script>



<div id="anotherUP" style="display: none; cursor: default">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="drop1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="drop1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input type="button" id="Button3" value="Click me to Bring Pop Up" onclick="bringPOPup()" />
        <br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here's the code behind,

```
 public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
 {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindDropDownList();
            }
        }

        protected void BindDropDownList()
        {
            using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), SelectCommand()))
            {
                System.Data.DataView dv = (System.Data.DataView)ds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                if (dv.Count > 0)
                {
                    drop1.DataSource = ds;
                    drop1.DataTextField = "UserName";
                    drop1.DataBind();
                    drop1.Items.Insert(0, "Please select a Username ");
                }
            }
            UpdatePanel2.Update();
        }

        protected void Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //while debugging never hits break point.
        }
}
```

**Update**

If I comment out `UpdatePanel2` then DDL doesn't reset but still doesn't trigger's code behind method.

Comment: There is no question, only a description of what your code does.

Comment: DDL resets when I select an item when it shouldn't, neither it's hitting code behind method

Comment: I created a usercontrol using your code and it worked fine. I suspect there is a postback conflict in the parent page.

Comment: @Ian thanks a lot for that, that might be the issue as it's sharepoint page where I am adding this user control, I might start thinking about any other approach

Comment: Add a SharePoint tag to your post so those experts can offer help.

Comment: I would simply it a bit. Remove all the update panels, to confirm that it works with out first. Then just have one updatepanel around the whole lot. Hide the Div initally. Change the <input tag to a proper .net runas="server". I have done this loads of time in Sharepoint webparts

Answer (score 1):

This is common problem with sharepoint event handling. Please try below code in page load.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Drop1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDropDownList();
        }
    }
```