# Can I use jquery Drop down list instead of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, webforms

At the moment I am using ASP.NET drop down list, but I am having problem with post backs, so I was wondering if I could use jquery select menu instead, not sure how to though, someone guide please,

Here's my ASP.NET drop down list code,

[Drop Down List resets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442809/drop-down-list-resets)

Here is the plugin I want to use,

http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/index.php?country_id=5&city_id=&vehicle_id=&language=

**Only thing I am confused is, how can I populate jQuery select menu using SQL DataSource.**

Comment: Have you tried to bind the data using an AJAX call on the code behind?

Comment: It seems like you didn't set the AutoPostBack=true property for that drop-down control.

Comment: I added autopostback but no good, check my other question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So essentially, you need a way to get the information from your server to the client. There are two ways you can do this.

1. Use an Ajax call to pull in your information.  Of course, in this case, you will need to create an endpoint for your Ajax to hit.

   ```
   var yourList;
   $.post("GetDataService.svc", function (returnData) {
       yourList = returnData;
   });
   ```
2. Save the server object as a javascript object using ASP tags.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var yourList = "<%=this.GetData() %>";
   </script>
   ```