# update button is not firing in update panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using update panel in popup menu to avoid fullpostback.
i have two button, one is add button and other is update button. add button is correctly firing.update button not firing when selection index changed in select2 list box jquery. below is my code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"  >
<ContentTemplate>
 <table>
<tr>
 <td>Customer Name:</td>
 <td><asp:ListBox ID="Customer_list" runat="server" style="width:250px"  AutoPostBack="true" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox></td>
 <td>Favourite Name:</td>
 <td><asp:DropDownList ID="fvr_Name" runat="server" style="width:250px"    
    AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="fvr_Name_SelectedIndexChanged"  /> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Name:</td>
 <td><asp:TextBox ID="Name_txt" runat="server" /></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><asp:Button ID="btn_Add" Text="Add" runat="server"  OnClick="Add_btn_Clicked" Enabled="true" /></td>
 <td></td>
 <td><asp:Button ID="btn_Update" Text="Update" runat="server" 
    onclick="btn_Update_Click"    /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers >
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Update" EventName="Click"  />
</Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

kindly help me to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

See this line in the `<Triggers>` section of the update panel:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Update" EventName="Click"  />
```

You need to add a new trigger for the selection index changed event:

```
<Triggers >
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_Update" EventName="Click"  />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="fvr_Name" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"  />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: thnk u for ur response. after read ur response. i edited my code that u posted. but update button not working ... pls help me

Comment: Hmm, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439037/drop-down-list-selected-index-changed-not-working-in-update-panel